# jQuery Sticky Plugin bottomSpacing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sticky, sticky-footer

I was trying to make a sticky banner at the bottom of the site, which happens to be not that super-easy unless I use jQuery Sticky Plugin. The problem is that Sticky is doing fine with sticky header (`topSpacing` parameter), but it has problems with `bottomSpacing` parameter, which is working for me just as `topSpacing`. I've done everything like in the example, so my header looks like:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#banner").sticky({topSpacing:0});
    });
</script>
```

So briefly, it works fine with sticky header, but replacing `topSpacing` with `bottomSpacing` doesn't change anything at all and in my opinion it should make the banner stick to the bottom instead of top. Am I doing something wrong?

@edit Here's the code I'm actually using:
http://pastebin.com/6fN0fjRP

Comment: Can you put up a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: i'm not sure how to use an external library such as sticky at jsfiddle, i mean is there any upload possibility?

Comment: I dont think so :( Can you show your html and CSS instead, if it's viable!

Comment: [link](http://pastebin.com/6fN0fjRP) this is it

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to open that link at office, it's prohibited (pastebin is). Although update this link in the question itself, others can help you out with it.

Comment: anyone solve this? i have same problem...